# Snowboarding in powdery trees

Tags: snowboarding

I have been snowboarding for 10 years on and off and would consider myself intermediate.  I am confident on all runs and most off piste situations but as soon as I get in tight trees with powder, I lose it.

Any tips on how to improve my style in trees with powder snow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3 things I've found for tight areas:

1. Wear a helmet, I've bounced off of trees and it HURTS.
2. Move both of your bindings back at the start of the day to help you keep your weight over the back, preventing the tip from digging in and sending you into a cartwheel.
3. Don't push too hard into the outer branches of the trees, the branches catch all the snow meaning there's often a big hole underneath that's very easy to fall into, and very hard to climb out of.

Comment: +1 - very good points. All have caught me out before :-)

Answer (score 4):

- Start your turns early, which will result in wider turns.
- Use minimal edge; keep board as flat as possible while maintaining control.
- Look where you're going (ideally, a couple turns ahead), rather than at the trees.

Answer (score 1):

**Work your way into tight areas.**

Go find some trees with a good bit of space between them, where you can start getting used to the flow of picking a side and how hard to cut into each one.

Gradually move into areas where the trees are tighter together. **If things get hairy**, don't try and come to a stand-still, you'll wind up hitting something anyway while you're out of position, which winds up being even worse. Instead, **focus on going left or right of every tree** (whichever you're more confident with or whichever works with the flow you're in). If you just focus on doing that **you'll eventually wind up bleeding off enough speed** to regroup or come to a stand still.

And definitely wear a helmet!